# ¿se puede dividir una api rest en aplicaciones con django rest framework asi como con django?

Tags: python, django, api

el origen de mi pregunta es que me encuentro con la necesidad de crear una API con django solo que me vengo encontrando que existe una extencion del framework llamada django rest framework.

Mi pregunta es, que si la api con django rest framework tambien se puede segmentar o divir por aplicaciones asi como django.

Answer (score 0):

Si, puedes hacerlo, creas una aplicación normal django y ya dentro de ella, procedes a crear los archivos que necesitas.
Este es un ejemplo burdo, de todo dentro de la app, como si hicieras una api sencilla:
users:

```
__init__.py
views.py
urls.py
serializers.py
models.py
```

También hay otro que dentro de la app de Django crean otro módulo y lo llaman **api** y dentro ya meten todo lo relacionado con API.
Ejemplo

users:

```
__init__.py
api/
   endpoints.py
   serializers.py
   models.py
views.py
urls.py
.
.
.
```

Mi recomendación.
Si tu proyecto va a ser enteramente de apis, entonces usa una estructura como la de arriba a tu preferencia, pero si en tu proyecto vas a crear apis, pero también vas a usar vistas con templates, entonces ve por la segunda opción, aunque no lo creas es común estar creando endpoints para api y a su vez vistas con templates de html

Espero haber ayudado.